# IQueryable to expression with literals

Tags: c#, ria, expression-trees, iqueryable

So I have the following scenario and I am not sure how to approach it.

In the app that we are building we have a ReferenceDataService which is used to load data via RIA serices. A query is built up on the client as an IQuerable and submitted to the server for retrieval.  Now most of the reference queries that are submitted are identical and called multiple times,  therefore I would like to service these queries from the entity cache instead.

Below is an example of the query expression that is generated and I have highlighted the  area where the query changes. There are some scenarios where the query has additonal criteria but the majority probably dont.

```
Chime.DataModel.classification[]
                .Where(c => ((value(Chime.Modules.Reference.Client.Agent.ReferenceDataLoader+<>c__DisplayClass20).includeSchema 
                        *AndAlso c.class_code.StartsWith(value(Chime.Modules.Reference.Client.Agent.ReferenceDataLoader+<>c__DisplayClass20).schema))* 
                        OrElse (Not(value(Chime.Modules.Reference.Client.Agent.ReferenceDataLoader+<>c__DisplayClass20).includeSchema) 
                        AndAlso *c.parent_code.StartsWith(value(Chime.Modules.Reference.Client.Agent.ReferenceDataLoader<>c__DisplayClass20).schema))))*
                .OrderByDescending(c => c.value_scheme_ind)
                .ThenBy(c => c.sequence_number)
                .ThenBy(c => c.class_label)
```

So what I would like to do is actually cache the query and if another comes in with identical criteria I can hit the cache.  The problem I have is that the literals used in the query do not seem to be available therefore I cannot determin if one query is different from another. The schema code for example is nowhere to be found. It must be sent the the server at some point but I am unsure how I can get at it.

Does anyone know a way to do this or come across this before?

Dave

Comment: The excerpt above is from calling ToString()?

Answer (score 2):

If you were using WCF Data Services, I would just say call ToString() on your IQueryable and it would return an exact URI of the query to be executed against the Data Service...and you could simply cache based on that string value.

As far as I know, RIA doesn't expose such hooks, so you'll have to rely on more traditional methods.

Implement an ExpressionVisitor that visits your IQueryable.Expression and computes a hash code for it.

You mentioned you can't see your constant string values in your expression tree. That's because they are not inlined yet into the expression tree and thus still exist as MemberAccessExpressions, not ConstantExpressions. To fix this, you can use a partial evaluating ExpressionVisitor. The source for such is given here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546158.aspx

Look at the Evaluator class.